# Get values between min and max in PHP object

Tags: php

I am trying to get the values between min and max in a PHP object.
This is the output of the PHP object:

```
var_dump($suggestions->productionYear);
```

Outputs:

```
object(stdClass)#6567 (2) { ["min"]=> int(2016) ["max"]=> int(2019) }
```

But I want to output all the values between the `min` and `max` like this: `2016` , `2017`, `2018` and `2019`

Does someone know how I get the output like above? I know I have to use a foreach loop but everytime I get output `NULL`

```
<?php foreach ($suggestions->productionYear as $productionYear) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $productionYear; ?>"
    ><?php echo $productionYear; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `range()` with `foreach()`, **See**: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

```
foreach (range($min, $max) as $year) {
   // other code goes here
}
```

**For your case something like,**

```
$min = $suggestions->productionYear->min;
$max = $suggestions->productionYear->max;

<?php foreach (range($min,$max) as $year) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>"
    ><?php echo $year; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither `min` nor `max` have any special meaning in PHP objects as you seem to assume. If you want your object to be iterable with `foreach` you need to make it implement the [`Iterator` interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). You can find a full implementation at [Example #1 Basic usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#example-333).

Otherwise, just build your own loop or generate a range:

```
$suggestions = (object)null;
$suggestions->productionYear = (object)['min' => 2016, 'max' => 2019];

for ($productionYear = $suggestions->productionYear->min; $productionYear <= $suggestions->productionYear->max; $productionYear++) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $productionYear; ?>"><?php echo $productionYear; ?></option>
<?php }

foreach (range($suggestions->productionYear->min, $suggestions->productionYear->max) as $productionYear) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $productionYear; ?>"><?php echo $productionYear; ?></option>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on var_dump, it outputs an object. So you first need to convert that into an array and then loop over it.

```
(array) $suggestions->productionYear;
```

Comment: It will still only have the `min` and `max` values with this solution.

Comment: Yes you are right @user3783243. I didn't work on that yet. I will update it soon. Thanks!:)